# Whenever I paste an image into Photoshop, transparency becomes black

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, transparency, photos, adobe-cs5

When I copy an image from a browser and paste it into PS, the transparency turns black. When I click "Save image as" and open the image with PS, the areas with partial transparency (50% transparent, etc) become non-transparent. Why is this? I have CS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use transparent document then past your image.might be you are ignoring background..check it..

Answer (score 1):

It is since windows uses 24-bit bitmaps while copy and pasting.

Save the file to disk and use open with.

Comment: When I do that, all areas with 50% transparency becomes opaque. I think it's because the image is in Index Color format. But when I open it with windows gallery, it's still 50% transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check you're pasting it into a file type which supports transparency. If you made a new JPG, for example, this might happen, as JPEG doesn't support transparency. PNG does.