# Photoshop, black color instead of transparency when pasting from clipboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipboard, transparency

After reinstalling Windows I got a problem that transparency is lost when I paste image from clipboard, from another program(like browser). Instead of transparency photoshop using full black color.

I remember this as a problem back in the days when you had to download, open and do copy-paste internally... But it's a temporary solution and I want a fix.

I also did a little bit of testing, to be sure what is causing issue and checked 
some combinations of copy-pasting from different browsers(Chrome, new Firefox, Opera) to different programs(Paint.NET and Discord). And I also tried to copy-paste from PS to Paint.NET and from Paint.NET to PS, and results are some inconsistent...

So. Every PNG picture that was copied to clipboard and pasted to Paint.NET save its transparency. As well as transparency saved throw Discord.

When pasting from any browser to PS transparent zones become black.

But, when you copy-pasting from PS to Paint.NET(and vise versa) transparency is not saved and transparency in both cases is white...

In my PS settings in General tab "Export Clipboard" option is checked, and in Export tab the "Quick Export Format" is set to PNG with Transparency.

I also find a dirty solution that should work — a browser extension "Open in Photoshop" that preserve transparency... but according to the latest reviews it's not working and it's a scum app...

Pls halp!!11 and sorry for bad English.

P.S. This is not my case: [Whenever I paste an image into Photoshop, transparency becomes black](https://superuser.com/questions/246327/whenever-i-paste-an-image-into-photoshop-transparency-becomes-black)

I'm pasting from clipboard into new testing image. And it's background is not black. I also did testing with already existing PNG file, for whatever reason, but it dosn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whenever I paste an image into Photoshop, transparency becomes black](https://superuser.com/questions/246327/whenever-i-paste-an-image-into-photoshop-transparency-becomes-black)

Comment: Different case. I'm pasting from clipboard into new testing image. And it's background is not black.

I also did testing with already existing PNG file, for whatever reason, but it dosn't help.

Comment: What is the colour mode of the file you are pasting into?

Comment: Clipboard?.. It should be in png format, my PS in RGB color mode and according to wiki PNG support only RGB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: Unless I understood your original post wrong, the PNG is the file you are copying *from*. What is the colour mode of the file you are pasting *to*?